# Colocar icono en una celda de una tabla hecha con semantic-ui

Tags: php, html, css, html5, semantic-ui

estoy usando Semantic-ui y en una página cargo una tabla, la que en las ultimas dos celdas de cada fila, coloco dos iconos que deben comportase como links a otros dos procesos como ser: editar el registro, o borrarlo.
Ahora bien... según la documentación de la gente de semantic-ui dicen que se podría cargar cada fila de la tabla de la siguiente manera:

```
   <tr>
     <td>Cell</td>
     <td>Cell</td>
     <td>Cell</td>
     <td>Cell</td>
     <td class="center aligned">
         <i class="eye icon"></i>
     </td>

     <td class="center aligned">
       <i class="delete icon"></i>
     </td>
   </tr>
```

Ahora bien, yo implemento cada fila como sigue dentro de un bucle while de PHP

```
<tbody>
      <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['usuario']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['correo']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row['last_session']; ?></td>
          <td class="center aligned">
            <i class="eye icon">
              <a href="modificar.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><p>Ver</p></a>
            </i>
          </td>

          <td class="center aligned">
            <i class="delete icon">
              <a href="eliminar.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><p>Borrar</p></a>
            </i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
```

Ahí tuve que hacer una tramoya medio rara como para poner un "ver" como para tener un link ya que no se cómo hacer que el icono se transforme en un "boton"... o de última colocar un botón en esa celda... no se... 
Alguien que tenga experiencia con semantic-ui podrá darme una mano ?
desde ya muchísimas gracias !!!

Vean como se ve !!!: HORRIBLE !!!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Que tal poniendo los íconos dentro de los enlaces?

```
<tbody>
  <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['usuario']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['correo']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['last_session']; ?></td>
      <td class="center aligned">
          <a href="modificar.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
            <i class="eye icon"></i>
          </a>
      </td>

      <td class="center aligned">
        <a href="eliminar.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">            
          <i class="delete icon"></i>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Shaz, ídolo !!! Mandame una foto que empiezo a hacerte un monumento !!!